# NameError: name 'marks' is not defined

Tags: python, flask, cassandra, cql

Here I am trying to fetch data from cassandra with filter() where I need to fetch students with more than or equal to 65 marks but I am getting this error can't understand why am I getting this error. I am referring [this](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.21/cqlengine/queryset/) link. I have also referred similar questions on this but didn't get any solution. 
Here is my python code:

```
from flask import *
from flask_cqlalchemy import CQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['CASSANDRA_HOSTS'] = ['127.0.0.1']
app.config['CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE'] = "emp"

db = CQLAlchemy(app)

class Student(db.Model):
    uid = db.columns.Integer(primary_key=True)
    marks = db.columns.Integer(primary_key=True)
    username = db.columns.Text(required=True)
    password = db.columns.Text()

@app.route('/merit')
    def show_merit_list():
        ob = Student.objects.filter(marks >= 65) 
        return render_template('merit.html', ml = ob)
```

And this is the error log I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/home/sudarshan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in 
__call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/home/sudarshan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in 
wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/home/sudarshan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in 
handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/home/sudarshan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in 
reraise
raise value
File "/home/sudarshan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in 
wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/home/sudarshan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in 
full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/home/sudarshan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in 
handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/home/sudarshan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in 
reraise
raise value
File "/home/sudarshan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in 
full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/home/sudarshan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in 
dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/home/sudarshan/Downloads/PycharmProjects/try/try1.py", line 67, in show_merit_list
ob = Student.objects.filter(marks >= 65)
NameError: name 'marks' is not defined
```

Comment: Try self.marks in your filter

Answer (score 2):

Pass `self` object to your method, hence allowing it to access `marks` data member.

Change `marks` to `self.marks`.

```
    @app.route('/merit')
    def show_merit_list(self):
        ob = Student.objects.filter(self.marks >= 65) 
        return render_template('merit.html', ml = ob)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well finally I found the answer I was forgetting to use allow_filtering(). The code will look like following:

```
@app.route('/merit')
def show_merit_list():
    ob = Student.objects().filter() #all()
    ob = ob.filter(Student.marks >= 65).allow_filtering()
    return render_template('merit.html', ml = ob)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Filtering Operators](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.21/cqlengine/queryset/#filtering-operators), try:

```
ob = Student.objects.filter(marks__gte=65)
```

Comment: but when I remove > symbol and keep only = symbol is working and showing all the students @explodinggayfish

Comment: You cannot use `>` symbol while passing parameter, if so the `marks >= 65` argument will be executed and converted to a `bool` variable, which will cause error because now `mark` is not a parameter name anymore but a variable. You can try `x = 5;print(x > 3)`

Comment: In this case I think there is something wrong either with your data or your query

Comment: does it have anything to do with allow_filtering().

Comment: 'cassandra.cqlengine.query.QueryException: Where clauses require either =, a IN or a CONTAINS (collection) comparison with either a primary key or indexed field. You might want to consider setting custom_index on fields that you manage index outside cqlengine.' is the error I am getting when I do like this 'ob = Student.objects.filter(Student.marks>=65)'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206965/discussion-between-sudarshan-a-and-explodinggayfish).